# CheckBox ListView control selection

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm following MVVM pattern. I have a listview control which has multiple checkboxes.
my viewmodel has collection of Student which is bounded to listview control.

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> students{ get; private set; }
private ObservableCollection<Student> _displays { get; set; }
```

viewmodel doesn't know anything about the view so it doesn't access to the listview control

I tried by defining the Student class by below

```
public class Student: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string class { get; set; }

    //Provide change-notification for IsSelected
    private bool _fIsSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _fIsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _fIsSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to perform some action in viewmodel when user select/deselect the checkbox.
how can achieve this? is it correct way to define above class?

Comment: Why don't you use treeview of checkboxes? Treeview has the property checkboxes - you have to set it to true, then you have the AfterCheck event. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Student` class knows when its values change, so you just need to add a `PropertyChanged` handler to your collection of `Student` objects in the view model. In this way, your view model can get notified when the values of the `Student` classes change. Try something like this:

```
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    student.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
}
```

...

```
private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
    {
        // The IsSelected property was changed
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to add a handler to *every* item in the collection. You could do that in a loop, as shown above, or by extending the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and overriding the `Add`, `Insert` and`Remove` methods and the constructors.

---

UPDATE >>>

Expanding on my final paragraph from above, you can extend the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and override the `Add` and `Remove` methods and the constructors... at its most basic, you could do something like this:

```
public class Students : ObservableCollection<Student>
{
    public Students(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        foreach (Student student in students) Add(student);
    }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        base.Add(item);
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        return base.Remove(item);
    }

    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify of all item property changes
        NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    // Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface properly here
}
```

The benefit of this method is that you can then just attach one handler to the collection, rather than having to manually attach them to each item:

```
Students.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how to do it in another way i.e. by extending the ObservationCollection<T> class and overriding add and remove method.